# How to protect asp.net or c# source file can be view or edit by client using compiler tools?

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, copy-protection

is there any way to protect the source code of asp.net or c# being view by client when they try to use re-edit it by using compiler tools?

i have check on .net reflector but only can use for 14 days for free.

please provide some information or example to use will be great for helping to understand , thank you.

Comment: You're asking about obfuscation. Google it. In general it's not possible to completely prevent your code being reverse-engineered since it still needs to be executed - with enough time, somebody can get source code back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case what you can do ,compile your source code into dll files. To do that you need to create New project Class Library for all your classes and functions. after compiling you will get Dll files. Add these files into your web application as reference.

Here is link to guide you through

[Creating Class Library](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/61b832/creating-class-library-in-visual-C-Sharp/)

Comment: thanks for the creating class library link tutorial 
by the way can "asp:button " or others "asp:Link" can be put in class as tutorial did and reference as dll?

Comment: There is no benefit of doing that if that possible because at then these are asp control. mostly people will compile their source code where their business logic and data layer resides. In other way ASP control reside in presentation layer which should be accessible to everyone